# SQL add new line if value is in second column also

Tags: sql, sql-server

So I am trying to pull the data from the table to give me each score the person has and if they have two scores I would like it to be on a new line with the second score. If the user has no scores I don't want anything returned. My query returns the first score if the user has one and if they don't it returns the second one. But if the user has two scores is where i'm not sure how to return that one on a new line.

table 1

```
+---------+--------+--------+
|  name   | score1 | score2 |
+---------+--------+--------+
| jim     | null   | 87     |
| doug    | 21     | 45     |
| brandon | null   | null   |
| susy    | 11     | null   |
+---------+--------+--------+
```

The result my query gives is

```
+------+----+
| jim  | 87 |
| doug | 21 |
| susy | 11 |
+------+----+
```

Wanted output

```
+------+----+
| jim  | 87 |
| doug | 21 |
| doug | 45 |
| susy | 11 |
+------+----+
```

The query I wrote is

```
SELECT
  name
 ,COALESCE(score1, score2)
FROM
  table
WHERE
  score1 IS NOT NULL
  OR score2 IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY
  name;
```

Comment: Use `APPLY` or `UNPIVOT`. e.g. `SELECT T.Name, C.Score FROM myTable AS T CROSS APPLY (VALUES (T.Score1), (T.Score2)) AS C(Score) WHERE C.Score IS NOT NULL;`

Comment: On an unrelated note, have a look [at this post](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips and tools for formatting your posts.

Comment: @ZLK  I didn't know you could cross apply to VALUES from the original table.  Thanks for teaching me something neat today.

Answer (score 1):

Treat this as two separate queries and combine the results together with `UNION ALL`. You'll want `UNION ALL` in this case and not just `UNION` so you get two rows returned in the case where the person has the same score in both columns.

```
SELECT name, Score1 as score
    FROM table1
    WHERE Score1 IS NOT NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT name, Score2 as score
    FROM table1
    WHERE Score2 IS NOT NULL 
ORDER BY name, score;
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend `cross apply`:

```
SELECT t.name, v.score
FROM table t CROSS APPLY
     (VALUES (score1), (score2)) v(score)
WHERE v.score IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY name;
```

This is usually the most efficient way to unpivot data in SQL Server.